# Cannot paste multiple lines text in SQL Server Compact table cell in Webmatrix

Tags: sql-server-ce, copy-paste, webmatrix

I am learning to create a database driven website in Webmatrix using ASP.NET Web Pages and SQL Server Compact. I want to manually enter data in DB tables but when I try to paste a block of text with line breaks in a table cell, only the first line is pasted.

How can I paste text with linebreaks into a SQL Server Compact database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have MS office, then you could use Access or even Excel to attach to the SQL Server using ODBC.